# Getting the error " bound must be positive" while trying to select a random radio button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[IMAGE OF LIST OPTIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DTh7.png)I am trying to select a random radio button out of multiple radio buttons through the below-mentioned code:

```
addapp.ClickSelectUnit();

List < WebElement > options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @name='application[unit_space_id]']"));

Random ran = new Random();

int index = ran.nextInt(options.size());

options.get(index).click();
```

But getting the error:

> 2019-10-31 20:24:50 ERROR TestUtilsRV:141 - bound must be positive
>   2019-10-31 20:24:52 INFO  TestUtilsRV:134 - Quit Driver

When I run the code in Debug Perspective by putting a breakpoint at the first line it selects the random checkbox but when I run it in maven through command prompt I keep getting this error. Please help me get through this.

Comment: `options` is empty. There is nothing for it to randomly pick from.

Comment: Hi Andy, I did not understand why you said options is empty, while debugging the code I took a snapshot of the elements which are present in options. Please check out the image in the description and help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: "bound must be positive" means that the argument passed to `Random.nextInt(int)` was zero or negative. It comes from a size, so it can't be negative, therefore it must be zero. Perhaps the dom elements aren't always present when you execute the `findElements`. Impossible to say without being able to run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made following changes to the code and it worked perfectly for me:

List options=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(xpath)));

@Andy: Yes, options was empty and by using the wait for visibility for the list elements the issue got resolved.